# Как собрать рабочую связку Symfony 4.3 + Doctrine 2.0 + MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine2, symfony4, doctrine-mongodb-odm

Первый опыт с Symfony 4 и Doctrine 2.0, и сразу грабли. Авторизацию и сессии держу на MariaDB (условие ТЗ - работа с существующей базой пользователей), проблем нет. Но **нужно подключить базу MongoDB в качестве рабочей для проекта**. Саму монгу слегка потрогал руками через консоль. PHP 7.3, ext-mongodb установлено.

Прогуглил тему, нашел 2 подхода.

Первый предлагает нам Symfony на основе [DoctrineMongoDBBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html). На PHP 7.x в лоб не становится, в качестве костыля предлагается поставить alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter (*в документации к Symfony об этом, к сожалению, не написано - потратил кучу времени на поиск*). [Описанный процесс](https://vfac.fr/blog/how-to-use-doctrine-mongo-db-with-symfony-4) еще не проверил, но с учетом того, что он датирован январем 2019, а Symfony 4.3 вышла в мае, не исключаю, что этот вариант морально устарел, а в документации об этом не написано.

Второй вариант описан в [официальной документации к Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.0/reference/introduction.html#setup) и основан на пакете doctrine/mongodb-odm. При этом он "оторван" от Symfony, при установке не создает никаких файлов в проекте - ни настроечных, ни классов, ничего (проверил на практике). Т.е. для начала работы потребуется очень вдумчиво курить мануалы и методом научного тыка пытаться заставить его работать в составе проекта Symfony 4.3.

На [англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine-odm+symfony4) информации по теме крайне мало, а то, что мне интересно, - вообще датировано прошлым годом, соответственно к 4.3 не относится. Дока Doctrine отсылает на оф. сайт Symfony, где я уже был. :(

Прошу совета "знатных кролиководов" в скрещивании ежа и ужа, то биш Doctrine и MongoDB, в среде Symfony 4 (в идеале - 4.3). Каким методом скрещивания воспользоваться для быстрого старта проекта? Мне кажется, я что-то упускаю.

Comment: _"На PHP 7.x в лоб не становится"_ а на что ругается?

Comment: На отсутствующую реализацию класса, описанного интерфейсом [MongoDB\Driver\Monitoring\CommandSubscriber](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.mongodb-driver-monitoring-commandsubscriber.php). Т.е. ставиться она - ставится. А при попытке отобразить любую страницу (без попытки использовавния монго) вылетает с исключением.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Мдя... Чего-то я точно не понимаю. Повторно восстановил проект с гитлаба, проставил по инструкции doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle, чтобы воспроизвести точное сообщение об ошибке, - и о чудо! Сообщение не выводится. Сейчас попробую прописать подключение к базе.

Comment: Может в предыдущей попытке композер не обновили? А восстановив проект заново скачали все либы?

Comment: Нет, пользовал `composer install`, судя по логу все либы брались из кэша.

Comment: Провел тестовые операции с базой - добавление / поиск документа. Операции прошли успешно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате изучения документации, ответов и комментариев к моему вопросу, и ряда проведенных экспериментов получилось следующее:

1. С выходом версии 4.0 бандла [DoctrineMongoDBBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html) и версии 2.0.1 пакета doctrine/mongodb-odm каких-либо дополнительных пакетов для работы с MongoDB под PHP 7.2 и выше (проверено на PHP 7.3.10) в среде Symfony 4 (проверено на версии 4.3.5) ставить не требуется. Достаточно установки DoctrineMongoDBBundle как описано в документации:

```bsh
composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle
```

По состоянию на сейчас при этом устанавливаются пакеты `doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle` v4.0.0 от 2019-10-02T14:20:29+00:00, `doctrine/mongodb-odm` v2.0.1 от 2019-10-09T07:24:51+00:00, `mongodb/mongodb` v1.4.3 от 2019-07-02T18:04:14+00:00.

Тестовые операции вставки / выборки документов у меня прошли успешно. Результат воспроизводим, проверил на практике.

2. Объяснить причину сбоя, произошедшего у меня при предыдущих попытках установки DoctrineMongoDBBundle 14-15 октября, т.е. уже *после* выхода в свет обновленных пакетов, мне не удалось. Возможно, "фазы Луны" или еще какой невоспроизводимый сбой. Во всех экспериментах (что успешных, что неудачных) использовалась одна и та же версия проекта из гитлаба (специально делал для обеспечения "чистоты эксперимента"), установка бандла шла точно по документации.
3. Для дальнейшего использования [версии 4.0.0 бандла DoctrineMongoDBBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/tree/4.0) следует иметь в виду следующее:

   - бандл требует PHP 7.2 или выше, ext-mongodb 1.5 или свежее, и работает с Symfony версий 3.4 и выше;
   - по состоянию на момент написания этого текста тесты у разработчиков бандла не прошли, так что нужно быть морально готовым к возможным проблемам при разработке. Ирония судьбы: по заявлению разработчиков бандл содержит только исправление ошибок и патчи системы безопасности. :)
4. Не смотря на не прошедшие тесты, я все же рискну писать проект, основываясь на этой версии бандла. Проведенные мной тестовые операции с базой вдохновляют. Ох, и нескушно же будет!..

Благодарю всех принявших участие в обсуждении, вы меня реально выручили. Ваши ответы и комментарии простимулировали меня на ускоренные телодвижения по экспериментированию. Отдельная благодарность @zalex, обратившему мое внимание на git пакета doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте попробую расписать, но не судите строго, педагог я так себе. Опять же, пишу применимо к Symfony 3.4, однако суть остается та же.

> скрещивании ежа и ужа, то биш Doctrine и MongoDB

Это не верное утверждение. Проект Doctrine c реляционными - это OEM, с нереляционными - ODM. Т.е. нельзя говорить о том что это скрещивание ибо это и есть их [проект](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.0/index.html).

Реализацию в Symfony вам как раз и предоставляет DoctrineMongoDBBundle

Теперь по поводу проблем, которые у вас возникли. (Я вот только что проверил и оказалось что вышла версия 2.0 ODM, что делает немного не актуальным мой ответ, однако я думаю пока бандл наврядли перевели на эту версию ибо релиз похоже был только-только.)

Так вот, ключевая сложность в том что ODM работали и работают до сих пор (я про версию 1.3.2 и ниже) с драйвером для php - [`php-mongo`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mongo.php), однако если вы перейдете по ссылке, вы увидите что это deprecated драйвер и в общем то в версии php 7.0 его попросту невозможно поставить. А вместо него появился [`php-mongodb`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/set.mongodb.php)
Вот мы и получаем такую историю, что бандл перестает работать. Какой же выход ? Разработчики из Doctrine сделали адаптер, который реализует функционал старого драйвера через новый. Вот и все. Это и есть `alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter`. А для того чтобы композер не ругался на отсутствия php-mongo которого уже нет вроде как, нужно прописать в composer.json

```
  "provide": {
    "ext-mongo": "*"
  }
```

наверняка это описано в документации ( я не ходил по ссылкам что вы приводили).

Однако сейчас я вижу что вышла версия 2.0 работающая уже с новым драйвером, но я буквально вчера вернулся из отпуска и завтра, благодаря вам, вовлекусь в удивительный процесс чтения перехода на новую версию.

p.s. Ну и это конечно не касается версии < 4 , т.к. ставится бандл на нее или нет, я не знаю. Я думаю что должен ставится без особых плясок, однако не могу ручаться.

upd. Ну в общем то все так как я и описал. Посмотрите, вышла новая версия бандла (не путайте с версией доктрины), где как раз используется новй драйвер. Вот правда тесты у них не прошли,но то такое ... [4.0](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/tree/4.0)

Ну и понятно что если у вас существует проект, то переводить рано и нужно подумать, а ежели только начинаете - то вот самое время.

Comment: Сборка рабочая. Проверил по composer.lock - добавились `doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle` v4.0.0 от 2019-10-02T14:20:29+00:00, `doctrine/mongodb-odm` v2.0.1 от 2019-10-09T07:24:51+00:00, `mongodb/mongodb` v1.4.3 от 2019-07-02T18:04:14+00:00. Действительно, свежак. Правда, так и не понял причину ранее возникших проблем. Неудачная попытка была 14-15 октября, уже _после_ выхода новых пакетов. Сейчас провожу эксперименты по воспроизводимости работоспособной сборки. Обидно будет получить траблу при выкате на продакшн.

Comment: Благодарю за дополнительную информацию. Бандл ставится без проблем, проверил несколько раз. Провел тестовые операции с базой - успешно. Фраза про "ежа и ужа" является шуткой и не отражает полноту моего понимания концепции "Document Mapping". :)